# SQL Server identify records accessed by a SQL command

Tags: sql-server

Is it possible to track records that are accessed by a `SELECT` command in a SQL Server database? In other words, I would like to find records in tables where without them the SQL command returns a different result. The list of records can possibly contains reasonable amount of false hits, but none of the necessary records should be missing.

I would like to avoid a SQL command analysis, since it can refer to many views, it can contains subqueries, computed values and so on. I can possibly identify tables used by a command and some tables are very large.

Comment: SQL analysis won't help - you can't know what data is accessed by a command unless you execute it. How would you know which `OrderItems` will be accessed if you don't know which `Orders` will be returned first?

Comment: Ok, and how do you identify the records if you can execute the command?

Comment: use sql profiler to find the underline connections to your database, i.e.. select, update delete.

Comment: Sql profiler doesn't tell anything about specific records accessed during an execution of an SQL command. It just capture SQL commands with several information and statistics about a command.